# If devas aren't sinless, how can we trust devas not to do wrong to us or to lie to us?

Tags: gods, philosophy

Sometime ago, a user here asked if devas were sinless, although I forgot the name of the question. The answers said no.

But if devas are not incapable of sinning, how can we trust them? How could we ever be secure?

I am coming to believe that devas are sinless, for the above reasons.

Comment: trust Bhagavan alone then

Comment: People hardly worship Devas anyway now because of this

Comment: @mar Yeah, but devas still govern the universe, even if we don't worship them.

Comment: I could be incorrect, am not 100% sure of anything, however I think you can trust your Ishth-Dev or Devi. I don’t believe they will harm you if you are their devotee and have sincerity and genuine feeling towards them 

Comment: @devibhakt But even the devas whom we do not actively worship still govern the universe.

Comment: @TerjijKassal Things will happen according to fate though, from what I understand. But I still think you can in general trust the highest level of Gods. There can be things you take issue with or don’t like, things you think aren’t ok cause of limited understanding, but I don’t think you will be lied to or betrayed by them. Just my opinion. Others may disagree. As a beginner bhakt, this is what I think, anyway 

Comment: "but devas still govern the universe" - under the supervision of Bhagavan. Bhagavan is like CEO, devas are like VP, Directors, Managers. If you go directly to CEO, no need to go to middle managers.

Comment: @mar So Bhagavan will not let the devas commit any sins against humans?

Comment: if they do, they will get fired just like any other employee. many times, indra got suspended due to bad actions and someone else took his place.

Comment: @mar Totally agree, yeah, I think you’re 100% correct here. Also is reassuring & comforting, thx for posting these comments 

Comment: @mar Are there any scholars who comment on what is happening, in technical language, when a deva gets "fired"?

Comment: common in puranas - indra loses indralok, and mahabali took over (temporarily). same with many other asuras capturing svarg after indra makes an offense and rishis curse him. @TerjijKassal

Comment: @mar So did Indra's jiva get sent back down away from Indralok and replaced with a new jiva?

Comment: Indra is a post, like MD, or COO. The current Indra lost his post, and someone else took up post of Indra e.g. Mahabali defeated Indra and took over Svarg Lok temporarily.

Comment: So the Indra, that held the post before Mahabali, was killed and sent to reincarnate in a new body?

Comment: @veganenvironmentalist I don't think you have the right attitude to Devas, you're acting as if they're your best friend and not as if they are one of the Powers that govern this universe.

Comment: Well. That is my beliefs as I was born into Hinduism. And cause I am very happily involved in Hindu religion. I love it so much. So I will see things from that kind of viewpoint. Also I fully agree w/ what mar is posting here in comments replies. I think is correct 